# Filter large file using python, using contents of another

Tags: python, optimization, filter, compare

I have a ~1GB text file of data entries and another list of names that I would like to use to filter them. Running through every name for each entry will be terribly slow. What's the most efficient way of doing this in python? Is it possible to use a hash table if the name is embedded in the entry?  Can I use make of the fact that the name part is consistently placed?

Example files:

Entries file -- each part of the entry is separated by a tab, until the names

```
246   lalala   name="Jack";surname="Smith"
1357   dedada   name="Mary";surname="White"
123456  lala   name="Dan";surname="Brown"
555555   lalala   name="Jack";surname="Joe"
```

Names file -- each on a newline

```
Jack
Dan
Ryan
```

Desired output -- only entries with a name in the names file

```
246   lalala   name="Jack";surname="Smith"
123456  lala   name="Dan";surname="Brown"
555555   lalala   name="Jack";surname="Joe"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first instinct was to make a dictionary of with names as keys, assuming that it was most efficient to look up the names using the hash of keys in the dictionary.

Given the answer, by @rfw, using a `set` of names, I edited the code as below and tested it against the two methods, using a `dict` of names and a `set`.

I built a dummy dataset of over 40 M records and over 5400 names. Using this dataset, the set method consistently had the edge on my machine.

```
import re
from collections import Counter
import time

# names file downloaded from http://www.tucows.com/preview/520007
# the set contains over 5400 names
f = open('./names.txt', 'r')
names = [ name.rstrip() for name in f.read().split(',') ]
name_set = set(names) # set of unique names
names_dict = Counter(names) # Counter ~= dict of names with counts

# Expect: 246   lalala   name="Jack";surname="Smith"
pattern = re.compile(r'.*\sname="([^"]*)"')

def select_rows_set():
    f = open('./data.txt', 'r')
    out_f = open('./data_out_set.txt', 'a')
    for record in f.readlines():
        name = pattern.match(record).groups()[0]
        if name in name_set:
            out_f.write(record)
    out_f.close()
    f.close()

def select_rows_dict():
    f = open('./data.txt', 'r')
    out_f = open('./data_out_dict.txt', 'a')
    for record in f.readlines():
        name = pattern.match(record).groups()[0]
        if name in names_dict:
            out_f.write(record)
    out_f.close()
    f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # One round to time the use of name_set
    t0 = time.time()
    select_rows_set()
    t1 = time.time()
    time_for_set = t1-t0
    print 'Total set: ', time_for_set

    # One round to time the use of names_dict
    t0 = time.time()
    select_rows_dict()
    t1 = time.time()
    time_for_dict = t1-t0
    print 'Total dict: ', time_for_dict
```

I assumed that a `Counter`, being at heart a dictionary, and easier to build from the dataset, does not add any overhead to the access time. Happy to be corrected if I am missing something.

Comment: Wow, thank you for timing both options and providing well-explained code for the process!

Comment: My pleasure. Glad you like it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `set` data structure to store the names — it offers efficient lookup but if the names list is very large then you may run into memory troubles.

The general idea is to iterate through all the names, adding them to a `set`, then checking if each name from each line from the data file is contained in the `set`. As the format of the entries doesn't vary, you should be able to extract the names with a simple regular expression.

If you run into troubles with the size of the names `set`, you can read *n* lines from the names file and repeat the process for each set of names, unless you require sorting.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a more efficient way to store the data entries, or is just a datafile.readlines() list as good as it gets? For example, storing each entry as a list, split by tabs[246, lalala, name="Jack";surname="Smith"

Comment: and splitting by " to get [246, lalala, name=", Jack, ";surname="Smith"], then checking if list[4] ("Jack") is in the name set?

Comment: Don't use `readlines` — instead, just iterate over the file (i.e. `for line in datafile`) — this will read the file line-by-line and not the entire content into memory.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is clearly structured as a table so this may be applicable.
[Data structure for maintaining tabular data in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038160/python-data-structure-for-maintaing-tabular-data-in-memory)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom data structure with its own "search by name" function. That'd be a list of dictionaries of some sort. This should take less memory than the size of your text file as it'll remove duplicate information you have on each line such as "name" and "surname", which would be dictionary keys. If you know a bit of SQL (very little is required here) then go with [Filter large file using python, using contents of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131938/filter-large-file-using-python-using-contents-of-another/11132174#11132174)