# Python categorize datatypes

Tags: python, numpy, sqlite

I plan to make a 'table' class that I can use throughout my data-analyzis program to store gathered data to. Objective is to make simple tables like this:

```
ID    Mean size     Stdv     Date measured    Relative flatness
----------------------------------------------------------------
1     133.4242      34.43    Oct 20, 2013    32093
2     239.244       34.43    Oct 21, 2012    3434
```

I will follow the sqlite3 suggestion from this post: [python-data-structure-for-maintaing-tabular-data-in-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038160/python-data-structure-for-maintaing-tabular-data-in-memory), but I will still need to save it as a csv file (not as a dbase) and I want it to eat my data as we go: add columns on the fly whenever new measures become available and are deemed to be interesting. For that the class will need to be able to determine the data type of the data thrown at it.

Sqlite3 has limited datatypes, float, int, date and string. Python and numpy together have many types. Is there an easy was to quickly decide what the datatype is of the variable? So my table class can automatically add a column when new data is entered containing new fields.

I am not too concerned about performance, the table should be fairly small.

I want to use my class like so:

```
dt = Table()
dt.add_record({'ID':5, 'Mean size':39.4334'})
dt.add_record({'ID':5, 'Goodness of fit': 12})
```

In the last line, there is new data. the Table class needs to figure out what kind of data that is and then add a column to the sqlite3 table. Making it all string seems a bit to floppy, I still want to keep my high precision floats correct....

Also: If something like this already exists, I'd like to know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your question is: "Is there an easy was to quickly decide what the datatype is of the variable?". This is a simple question, and the answer is: 
    `type(variable)`.
But the context you provide requires a more careful answer.

Since [SQLite3 only provides only a few data types (slightly different ones than what you said), you need to map your input variables to the types provided by SQLite3.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-types)
But you may encounter further problems: You may need to change the types of columns as you receive new records, if you do not want to require that the column type be fixed in advance.

For example, for the `Goodness of fit` column in your example, you get an int (12) first. But you may get a float (e.g. 10.1) the second time, which shows that both values must be interpreted as floats. And if next time you receive a string, then all of them must be strings, right? But then the exact formatting of the numbers also counts: whereas 12 and 12.0 are the same when you interpret them as floats, they are not when you interpret them as strings; and the first value may become "12.0" when you convert all of them to strings.

So either you throw an exception when the type of consecutive values for the same column do not match, or you try to convert the previous values according to the new ones; but occasionally you may need to re-read the input.

Nevertheless, once you make those decision regarding the expected behavior, it should not be a very difficult problem to implement. 
Regarding your last question: I personally do not know of an existing implementation to this problem.

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much what I ended up doing. Regarding the column type, I assume the type remains fixed after the first data. The problem and nuisance with `type(variable)` is when you have other, non-basic types, such as numpy. `type(numpy.array([1,2])[1])` will  give you `numpy.int32`. And there are lots of other possible outcomes. This makes making a mapping harder: I need to figure all possible input datatypes.