# Accessing in memory database or Table Using cx_Oracle

Tags: python, cx-oracle, in-memory-database

I havea  larger script in python, using the cx_Oracle module. I wanted to try to access and join a table created in memort. I can't seem to find any documentation on it. The closest I ahev found is an example using sqlite connect method found in in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038160/data-structure-for-maintaining-tabular-data-in-memory):

```
db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
```

Is there a way to do this in cx_Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's in-memory database product can be found here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/timesten/overview/index.html. If you're looking for something more "quick and dirty", however, you might want to dump the data into a SQLite memory database and use that instead to perform your query.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [Oracle Database 'In-memory' option](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/INMEM/toc.htm) then your cx_Oracle script connects to the Oracle DB and queries the table as if it were a normal table.